# Building weka classifier

Tags: classification, weka, text-classification, training-data

I'm trying to build a classifier in Weka. I have two data sets: training and testing. The two files are identical:  with the same number and type of attributes. However, the weka explorer is giving me error saying Train and test set are not compatible. How to resolve this error?
Here is a snap of the two sets:
[training set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mmLe.png)

[testing set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkBcM.png)

Comment: this question is a duplicate of many : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bweka%5D++not+compatible

Answer (score 0):

Searching through their wiki, here's what i found:

One of Weka's fundamental assumption is that the structure of the training and test sets are exactly the same. This does not only mean that you need the exact same number of attributes, but also the exact same type. In case of nominal attributes, you must ensure that the number of labels and the order of the labels are the same.

https://weka.wikispaces.com/Why+do+I+get+the+error+message+%27training+and+test+set+are+not+compatible%27%3F

They may seem to be the same but you never know, you should at least try one of the visual diff applications suggested by them.

I hope this helped you in some way.